# Does anyone knows the difference betwee groupadd id and subgid?

Tags: linux-kernel, namespaces

we can

> groupadd somegroup
>
> useradd -g somegroup user1

after useradd, we can find related /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid both with following format:

> user1:165536:65536

The question is that for those subgid, those ids not include somegroup id (**maybe 1001, it is far less than 165536**).

Does anyone know what's that means?  I googled a lot. still not quite understand.

Comment: `man subuid` & `man subgid`

Comment: Hi, I have read that subuid, and subgid. my question is that, why  those ids not include somegroup id(maybe 1001, it is far less than 165536).